# Are tasks parallelized when executed via an ExecutorCompletionService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I submitted 5 jobs to an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), but it *seems* like the jobs are executed in sequence. The ExecutorService that is passed to the constructor of [ExecutorCompletionService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) is created using newCacheThreadPool form. Am I doing anything wrong ?

**UPDATE** Each job is basically doing a database query & some calculation. The code for the ExecutorCompletionService is lifted as-is off the javadoc. I just replaced the Callables with my own custom Callable implementations.

Comment: Could you post some code please?

Comment: What are these jobs? They might be blocking on a sequential thing?

Comment: How do you observe this sequential behavior?

Comment: At the completion of each job, I add the result into a Queue.

Comment: Do you accidentally share the same connection or do you perform all operations on the same (set of) table(s)?

Comment: Do you perform this queue addition in the job itself or you use the get() method of the callable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExecutorCompletionService` has *nothing* to do with how jobs are executed, it's simply a convenient way of retrieving the results.

`Executors.newCachedThreadPool` by default executes tasks in separate threads, which *can* be parallel, given that:

- tasks are independent, and don't e.g. synchronize on the same object inside;
- you have multiple hardware CPU threads.

The last point deserves an explanation. Although there are no guarantees, in practice the Sun JVM favours the currently executing thread so it's never swapped out in favour of another one. That means that your 5 tasks might end up being executed serially due to the JVM implementation and not having e.g. a multi-core machine.

Comment: The purpose of the cached tp is to start new threads if there are more work waiting in the work queue. Even in single core case the JVM (on Windows and Linux) will start new worker threads for the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()). If so, execution should be parallelized as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> Each job is basically doing a database query & some calculation. The code for the ExecutorCompletionService is lifted as-is off the javadoc. I just replaced the Callables with my own custom Callable implementations.

In that case, are you sure you're not mistaken in thinking they're *executed* sequentially because you're *retrieving* the results sequentially?
Throw in some debug logging lines in your callables to rule this out, and/or have a look at this limited usage scenario:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Callable<String>> list = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();
    list.add(new PowersOfX(2));
    list.add(new PowersOfX(3));
    list.add(new PowersOfX(5));
    solve(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), list);
}

static void solve(Executor e, Collection<Callable<String>> solvers) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(e);
    for (Callable<String> s : solvers)
        ecs.submit(s);
    int n = solvers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String r = ecs.take().get();
        if (r != null)
            System.out.println("Retrieved: " + r);
    }
}

static class PowersOfX implements Callable<String> {
    int x;
    public PowersOfX(int x) {this.x = x;}
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sb.append(Math.pow(2, i)).append('\t');
            System.out.println(Math.pow(x, i));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Executing this you'll see the numbers are generated intermixed (and thus executed concurrently), but retrieving the results alone wont show you this level detail..

Answer (score 0):

The execution will depend on a number of things. For example:

- the length of time it takes to complete a job
- the number of threads in the thread pool (a cached thread pool will only create threads if it thinks they are needed)

Executing in sequence is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: It should be at least concerning in a multi-core environment.

Comment: If the jobs are short-lived then the pool may only ever need to create a single thread to execute them all. In this case only a single core will be used.

Comment: Yes, in case the job runs faster than you can submit task to the ES.